# Loader.load and Loader.loadBytes differences

Tags: actionscript-3, air, actionscript-2

I'm loading as2 swf into AIR application. It works properly when loaded from **file**. But when loaded from **bytes**, it is broken in some way (it reacts to mouse, but *some* elements are inactive)

```
var bytes:ByteArray = ... //loaded from resources
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false);
context.allowCodeImport = true; //this is neccessary
// Method 1 - blocks some scripts in loaded SWF
//context.applicationDomain = new ApplicationDomain();
// (application domain has no effect with as2 swf)
//context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain; //gives error 2114: securityDomain must be null
loader.loadBytes(bytes, context);
// Method 2 - loads properly
//loader.load(new URLRequest(file.url));
```

So why not just load it from file? My resources are protected with encryption and I can't dump them to disk - they must still be protected.

What tricks may exist to **load from bytes properly**?

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605791/loadercontext-and-applicationdomain-changes-with-adobe-air), but in my case as2 causes more problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS2 and AS3 use different runtimes (bytecode is different) so you won't be able to properly execute any AS2 bytecode in the AS3 runtime. you are basically injecting AS2 code into your AS3 application, so it ain't gonna work :/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder why the same AVM1 code works fully when loaded from file, and is partially broken when loaded from bytes.

Comment: i think it's because the `load` method treats the SWF as an asset and knows to run it in an AVM1 instance, while the `loadBytes` method  injects the AVM1 bytecode into your AVM2 bytecode which causes problems.

Comment: Maybe this is right (only Adobe engineers may know for sure.) In any case, it seems this is bug. I solved the issue long ago by remaking AS2 SWF (same functionality made different way.), no direct solution found.

Answer (score 2):

According the the documentation for [`LoaderContext`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html#applicationDomain) you should only use the `applicationDomain` property only when loading ActionScript 3.0 SWFs. Try dropping that parameter (or setting it to null) and see what happens.

Comment: That's correct, although I tried all combinations of parameters (null domain too). It seems there's no solution - AVM1 & AVM2 interaction is bugged.

Comment: not to harp on this, but its because your injecting AVM1 bytecode into an AVM2 swf, which just won't work :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that old SWF movies (AS1 and AS2, which require AVM1) loaded into an AIR app with `load` get put in their own domains, but those loaded with `loadBytes` share a domain. So if you have multiple AVM1 SWFs loaded with `loadBytes` their `_global` properties will clobber each other. This affects the Flash MX UI components (ca. 2002).

I can't be the only one trying to package ancient Flash files in AIR apps, so I figure this info may be useful to someone.